# Schema.org for educational software

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

My small company develops educational software that teaches algebra, geometry, and other math subjects.  The software is designed for desktop Windows PCs.  We have a website through which we sell the software, and each software package has its own page.

I would like to add Schema.org markup (using JSON-LD) to these product pages so that our search results listings would be richer and more descriptive.  But I am struggling to understand the different types and categories
of products that Schema.org defines.  My goal is to specify as closely as possible the details of each software product.

For example, I sell a program that teaches high school algebra.  If I were to invent my own categories and sub-categories to specify the product I would do it like this:

> Product -> Software -> Educational -> Math -> Algebra

But I don't see a hierarchy like that in the Schema.org documentation.

Instead I see the following:

> Thing -> CreativeWork -> SoftwareApplication

Within `SoftwareApplication` I see `applicationCategory` with "Game" as an example. But I don't see a list of other possible categories, like "Educational". Do you make up your own categories, or do you select from pre-defined choices?

And there is `applicationSubCategory` with "arcade game" as an example.
I don't know how to view the other possible sub-categories.  I would choose "Math" if it is allowed.  Additionally, I would like to have a sub-SubCategory, where I would specify "algebra".

Can anyone offer some guidance on how to categorize my products in Schema.org?

Comment: You said you want to provide Schema.org because you want to get rich search results. Do you have specific rich results in mind? If yes, which one(s)? The question is whether you only want to fulfill the specific rich result’s requirements, or if you want to provide the best representation Schema.org can offer, no matter whether it helps for getting rich results.

Comment: I would like to get the best representation Schema.org can offer.